# Change long python list with different layer with uniform one

Tags: python

I have one long list such as:

```
m=[[["a", "b"],["c","d"]],[["1", "2"],["3","4"]]]
```

How could I change it into one list as:

```
[["a", "b"],["c","d"],["1", "2"],["3","4"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested list comprehension:

```
[s for l in m for s in l]
```

With your sample input, this returns:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

Comment: or even just `sum(m, [])`

Comment: Really thx! It works.

Comment: @SamMason While concise, using `sum` is inefficient since for each add operation that joins two sublists there would be a new list created.

Comment: @blhsing good point! another version is `l = []; for a in m: l.extend(a)` which is generally faster than your solution, but isn't a nice single line